# Get Touch Event on entire screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a disappearing header which I want to bring back into the view on a single tap anywhere on the screen. But if I am wrapping the entire `<View>` inside a `<TouchableX>` component the PanResponder stops working. Is there a hack around this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just bind a touch event to the document, window, or body and respond with an appropriate function?

Comment: @Epik: sorry about the confusion. This is for react-native.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to warp it with `Touchable` component.

Add next props to root `View`.

[onResponderGrant](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onrespondergrant) - make `View` handle touch

[onStartShouldSetResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onstartshouldsetresponder) - make `View` handle start

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. FYI for anyone coming here via google, I implemented the touch handler and also added a 100ms delay to detect if the user actually did want to just touch on the screen.

Comment: I'm pretty new to react native, but if possible could you write an example of this?

Comment: This only works if you can wrap the View at the very root of your dom and it will be tricky to pass listeners from deeply nested components

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate @Nicholas Chong advice, here is the example that works for me fine. You can use `onTouchStart` and `onTouchEnd` handlers on any `View` via props:

```
<View
  onTouchStart={() => doSomething()}
  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
/>
```

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48754840/4791116)

Answer (score 1):

onResponderGrant not working for me, and I use onTouchEnd to trigger when tap the screen, this will work

Answer (score 0):

This would be an example of a implementation with a `onResponderGrant`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.startTouch = this.startTouch.bind(this);
    this.stopTouch = this.stopTouch.bind(this);
    this.onTouchE = this.onTouchE.bind(this);
  }

  startTouch() {
    console.debug("You start so don't stop!??");
  }

  stopTouch() {
    console.debug("Why you stop??");
  }

  onTouchE() {
    console.debug("Touchable Opacity is working!!");
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}
            onResponderGrant = { () => this.startTouch() }
            onResponderRelease = { () => this.stopTouch() }
            onStartShouldSetResponder = { (e) => {return true} }
            >
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = { () => this.onTouchE() }
          >
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
              Welcome to React Native!
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'cornflowerblue',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included an example of using `onResponderGrant` and `onStartShouldSetResponder` inside of a View component.

(Thanks to your previously written answer, @Mr Br)

### Definitions

```
import { Modal, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useState } from "react";
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
const dismissFunction = () => setVisible(false);
```

### Presentation

```
<Modal visible={visible} transparent style={{ alignItems: "center", height: "100%", }} >
  <View onResponderGrant={dismissFunction} onStartShouldSetResponder={dismissFunction} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#1c1c1c75", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "flex-end", alignItems: "center" }}  >
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#1E2124", borderRadius: 30, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", height: "30%", shadowColor: "#ffffff10", shadowOpacity: 10, shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: -5 }, width: "101%" }}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "#ffffff", fontSize: 24, marginLeft: "10%", marginRight: "10%", marginBottom: "10%", marginTop: "5%" }}>The message of your modal!</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Don't forget to run `setVisible(true)` somewhere to get the modal to show!