# How to catch the tap down event on React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to catch the event when a user taps on the view. Currently, I use the `TouchableXXX` components to catch user `onPress` (seems like `onPress` catches the `onTapDown` event only).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accepted answer does not work anymore. The correct way is to use Touchable's onPressIn()

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#onpressin

Answer (score 18):

You can set `onTouchStart` and `onTouchEnd` handlers on any `View` via props, for example:

`<View onTouchStart={() => this.doSomething()} />`

For general information about RN touches see the [Handling Touches](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.html) guide. In case you need a more complex, or custom touch handling, see the [Gesture Responder System](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

The current way is like that:

```js
<View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true} onResponderGrant={doSomething}>
</View>
```

[Source](https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system)